# Поддерживает ли xcode кодогенерацию на основе файлов интерфейса?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, интерфейс

В проекте `Xcode` у меня есть файл `storyboard` который содержит графическое представление `ios` проекта. В других интегрированных средах(ИС) разработки я встречал, что ИС генерирует код, на основании того, какие графические элементы (кнопки или поля ввода) я добавил во вью. Внимание вопросы:

1. Поддерживает ли Xcode генерацию кода на основании файлов `storyboard` и `xib`
2. Если да, то как найти код графического интерфейса, чтобы внести изменения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правой кнопкой по storyboard или xib файлу > Open As > Source Code

Comment: Вы знаете, чёрт возьми, это то что мне нужно. Спасибо!